# makefile explicitly linking multiple dynamic libraries

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to put together a simple makefile example like so:

```
FLAGS = -std=c++14
INC= -I/usr/local/include
LI = -L/usr/local/lib
LIB = /usr/local/lib/
LIBS =  $(LIB)libboost_filesystem-mt.a \
    $(LIB)libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib \
    $(LIB)libboost_filesystem.a \
    $(LIB)libboost_filesystem.dylib \
    $(LIB)libboost_system-mt.a \
    $(LIB)libboost_system-mt.dylib \
    $(LIB)libboost_system.a \
    $(LIB)libboost_system.dylib

default:
    g++ main.cpp $(FLAGS) $(INC) $(LI) $(LIBS) -o assemble
    ./assemble

clean:
    rm assemble
```

Is there a way to not have to prepend $(LIB) so many times? That's the only way I can get this to work right now (the above doesn't).

Comment: I would have thought that the `-L/usr/local/lib` already takes care of that; with that `-L` flag, there's no need to prepend the directory name.

Comment: It's unclear to me though, why you link both dynamic *and* static libraries.

Comment: @Evert, it doesn't. It's unclear to me, also. This is what worked in the past. I can certainly play around with it, but for now I'm just concerned with the question at hand.

Comment: Ah, I (and you) missed the lack of the `-l` flag; but the $(LIB) prefix still isn't necessary, even though MadScientist's answer includes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the linker to search the path you have to add libraries using the `-l` flag.  So instead of adding `libboost_system-mt.a` to your link line, you have to add `-lboost_system-mt` to your link line.  Then the linker will search the paths provided by `-L`.

I'm not sure about the `dylib` stuff; I don't do much with OS X.

In any event, if you're using GNU make you can do this:

```
LIBNAMES := filesystem-mt filesystem system-mt system

LIBS := $(foreach N,$(LIBNAMES),$(LIB)libboost_$N.a $(LIB)libboost_$N.dylib)
```